# Subdomain redirecting to another server

Tags: redirect, dns, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I have a website hosted on a shared hosting plan. My domain name is registered at GoDaddy, and the nameservers are those of my shared hosting (so far, all normal).

But I'm trying to figure out how to add a subdomain and point it somewhere else. I would like to point sub.mydomain.com to some other ip (on Amazon AWS). I would like to have it behave like a normal domain, and not a simple header('Location: ...') or window.location.href.

Is this even possible? If so, how do I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is possible. In the GoDaddy Control Panel, edit your DNS Zone File and add a "A record" for the subdomain. You should already have a A record for your main domain mapped to "@". Add a new entry using the subdomain prefix as host, e.g.:

```
Host    Points To

@       <main domain IP address>
sub     <subdomain IP address>
```

The second line should allow you to access the subdomain using `sub.mydomain.com`, while the main domain will still be accessible using `mydomain.com`.

Comment: It looks like a good solution, but GoDaddy tells me this : The zone file is unavailable because the domain's set nameservers do not belong to this registrar. I don't have a DNS on my server since it's only shared hosting, so I don'T think it can work that way

Comment: Ok I see now, it's shared hosting so you don't have access to the DNS manager in GoDaddy. This will not work then. I would suggest to check with your hosting provider to see if they allow additional subdomains or have a way to change the DNS servers for your domain.

Comment: If you have control of the domain, you can switch what servers are handling DNS. You could switch all dns to route 53 and have full control of the records.

Comment: Just saw that instead of changing it in GoDaddy, I could edit the DNS Zones directly in my cPanel. I've done this and it works now! Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, I had a similar [question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/65506/parent-domain-on-gae-and-sub-domain-on-aws), except that my domain/website is hosted on GoDaddy/Google App Engine (e.g. http://www.company.com). I want to set up an application in AWS and use it as a sub-domain of my website - e.g. http://app.company.com. Does this answer apply to my situation? Also, is there any benefit to using Route53 versus GoDaddy?

Comment: @WebUser Yes, it should work in your situation. I think that the main benefit of using Route 53 is better integration with other Amazon services. But for a simple setup with just one or two servers, it's probably not worth it. See also this question: http://serverfault.com/q/216330/127114

Answer (score 1):

**Server main domain**

[www.maindomain.com](http://www.maindomain.com)

**Another server subdomain**

blog.maindomain.com

**Zone Editor | DNS Editor**

@    => A => 72.2.116.95 = main domain

blog => A => 52.2.154.23 = subdomain in another server

font: https://css-tricks.com/put-a-subdomain-on-a-different-server/