# Point subdomain to another domain in the server

Tags: dns, plesk

I have a server with Plesk and CentOS.

> http://cdn.oyunlar1.com/images/8836.jpg file is located in server A.
>
> http://www.oyunlar1.com/modaokulu.html file is located in server B.

I basically want the same thing except I want to locate media files in a different domain instead of different server. Like this:

> user visits cdn.mydomain.com/file.swf
>
> but they actually read files from mydomain2.com/file.swf

I tried changing IP of A record of the subdomain to mydomain2.com's IP but it didn't work.

How can I do it?

Edit: I want to do this because it will help me to change my hosting provider very quickly and easily becuse media files are +100GB and the rest is like 10MB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subdomain redirecting to another server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860938/subdomain-redirecting-to-another-server)

Comment: Create a pointer on your HTTP server ( Apache, Tomcat etc) and set a VirtualHost with the domain you want and change the path to the folder you want it to go on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was simply adding CNAME record to mydomain.com of mydomain2.com and using htaccess at mydomain2.

Comment: What did your .htaccess file look like?